# How to sort a list of class instances

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

I'm operating with GAE and memcache. For my list of books I make a key and store it in memcache in order to avoid hit database everytime I must view the list.

When I add a new item to database, I add it to memcache key also, but a the start of the list, like this (self, in this case, is the book entity):

```
class Book(ndb.Model):
    """ A Book """
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    author = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)

    # Add a new element to memcache
    def add_to_memcache(self):
        data = memcache.get('mybooks')
        if data:
            logging.info('Adding to Memcache for key %s.', 'mybooks')
            data.insert(0, self)
            if not memcache.set('mybooks', data):
                logging.error('Memcache set failed for key %s.', 'mybooks')

    @classmethod
    def get_all(cls):
        key = 'mybooks'
        books = memcache.get(key)
        if books is None:
            books = list(Book.query().order(Book.title).fetch(100))
            if not memcache.set(key, books):
                logging.error('Memcache set failed for key %s.', key)
        else:
            logging.info('Memcache hit for key %s.', key)
        return books

    @classmethod
    def save(cls, **kwargs):
        book = cls(title=kwargs['title'],
                author=kwargs['author']
                )
        book.put()
        # Modify memcache for this key
        book.add_to_memcache()
        return book
```

So, at the first read of memcache, all is ordered, but with a new book, the list is not ordered anymore.

I tried to make:

```
data.insert(0, self)
data = sorted(data, key=itemgetter(1))
```

But I got the error *TypeError: 'Book' object does not support indexing*

Any suggestion for indexing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer:  I don't know much about GAE, so this answer is purely about sorting.*

---

First, you can't access class attributes with `operator.itemgetter` directly without implementing a `__getitem__` method, as classes are basically dictionaries - so it's attributes are not ordered.

*Example:*

```
In [1]: from random import shuffle

In [2]: from operator import itemgetter

In [3]: rand = range(10)

In [4]: shuffle(rand)

In [5]: rand
Out[5]: [1, 9, 2, 5, 4, 3, 0, 6, 8, 7]

In [6]: class A(object):
   ...:     def __init__(self, n):
   ...:         self.n = n
   ...:     def __repr__(self):
   ...:         return str(self.n)
   ...:     

In [7]: sorted([A(n) for n in rand], key=itemgetter(0))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-33ca678e282d> in <module>()
----> 1 sorted([A(n) for n in rand], key=itemgetter(0))

TypeError: 'A' object does not support indexing
```

---

```
In [8]: class A(object):
   ...:     def __init__(self, n):
   ...:         self.n = n
   ...:     def __repr__(self):
   ...:         return str(self.n)
   ...:     def __getitem__(self,ind):
   ...:         return self.n
   ...:     

In [9]: sorted([A(n) for n in rand], key=itemgetter(0))
Out[9]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

---

**But perhaps you have somewhat better options available:**

You can use `operator.attrgetter`; for `Book` instances (sorted by title) this would be:

```
sorted(data, operator.attrgetter('title'))
```

---

You may write a more generic key function for sorting:

```
def key_func(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, Book):
        return obj.title
    elif isinstance(obj, SomeOtherClass):
        return obj.some_other_attr
    else:
        raise TypeError('Unknown object!!!')

#  usage: sorted(data, key=key_func)
```

---

Or you can implement a `__cmp__` method for each class, so sorting would work without a
 key function:

```
def __cmp__(self, other):
    return cmp(self.attribute_you_want_to_be_compared, other)
```

*Example:*

```
In [10]: class A(object):
    ...:     def __init__(self, n):
    ...:         self.n = n
    ...:     def __repr__(self):
    ...:         return str(self.n)
    ...:     def __cmp__(self, other):
    ...:         return cmp(self.n, other)
    ...:     

In [11]: sorted([A(n) for n in rand])
Out[11]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to apply your solution to my Book Model. You have a list of numbers, but I have a list of entities, and I want to order by a specific attribute of my items (for example, order by title, which is first attribute of the book item). I have to say, also, that I'm working with Python for 2 months only, so maybe not all is obvious for me.

Comment: HEY, you did it, thank you very much!! I don't understand exactly how lambda can know that x is my model, but it worked perfectly. But another problem appeared: I want to index by the item position, not the literal. For example, something like `key=lambda x: x(1)` instead of x.title, because I'm actually sharing this functions for more than one model, which always 1st field is the order field. How can I order by field index?

Comment: Yeeesss, you are the boss, @root! I must make a little change in order to work, but now it works like a charm!! I will put the final solution here right now. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Here the final solution for the problem, may be useful for some other "stacker".
The key is the line

```
data = sorted(data, key=lambda self: self.key_func())
```

which will get each item from the data list (with the lambda function) and call the key_func that will evaluate the object type to order by the right field.
Thanks to @root for this solution.

```
class Book(ndb.Model):
    """ A Book """
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    author = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)

    def key_func(obj):
            if isinstance(obj, Book):
                return obj.title
            else:
                raise TypeError('Unknown object!!!')

    # Add a new element to memcache
    def add_to_memcache(self):
        data = memcache.get('mybooks')
        if data:
            logging.info('Adding to Memcache for key %s.', 'mybooks')
            data.insert(0, self)
            data = sorted(data, key=lambda self: self.key_func())
            if not memcache.set('mybooks', data):
                logging.error('Memcache set failed for key %s.', 'mybooks')

    @classmethod
    def get_all(cls):
        key = 'mybooks'
        books = memcache.get(key)
        if books is None:
            books = list(Book.query().order(Book.title).fetch(100))
            if not memcache.set(key, books):
                logging.error('Memcache set failed for key %s.', key)
        else:
            logging.info('Memcache hit for key %s.', key)
        return books

    @classmethod
    def save(cls, **kwargs):
        book = cls(title=kwargs['title'],
                author=kwargs['author']
                )
        book.put()
        # Modify memcache for this key
        book.add_to_memcache()
        return book
```

Note: the add_to_memcache function is intended to be shared in more than one class, but I have put it inside Book for asking only.